# Error when send email in codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I've trouble when send and email in codeigniter; the Error Is 
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Asset::$email_ctrl
>
> Filename: controllers/asset.php
>
> Line Number: 787
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function send_email() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\asset_apps\application\controllers\asset.php on line 787

please help. Thank you very much for your help

this is my controller ;

```
public function tambahassetproses() {

    $varkodeasset   =$this->input->post('idasset');
    $varassetacc    =$this->input->post('idassetacc');
    $varnmasset     =$this->input->post('nmasset');
    $variddpj       =$this->input->post('iddpj');
    $varidper       =$this->input->post('idper');
    $varlokasi      =$this->input->post('idlokasi');
    $varkategory    =$this->input->post('idkat');
    $varmacaddr     =$this->input->post('macaddr');
    $varssn         =$this->input->post('serialnum');
    $varmodel       =$this->input->post('smodel');
    $varmanufacture =$this->input->post('manufacture');
    $varstatus      =$this->input->post('status');
    $licence_qty    =$this->input->post('licenceqty');

    if ($varstatus == 'on')
    {
        $varstatus = '1';
    }
    else
    {
        $varstatus = '0';
    }

    $vardpjdate     =$this->input->post('datedpj');
    $varaccdate     =$this->input->post('dateacc');
    $varsusut       =$this->input->post('masasusut');
    $varstatustrn   = 'N';


    $object =   array ( 
                        'kodeasset' => $varassetacc,
                        'nama_asset' => $varnmasset,
                        'iddpj' => $variddpj,
                        'idperush' => $varidper,
                        'idlokasi' => $varlokasi,
                        'idkategory' => $varkategory,
                        'mac_addr' => $varmacaddr,
                        'serialnumber' => $varssn,
                        'smodel' => $varmodel,
                        'manufacture' => $varmanufacture,
                        'flagstatus' => $varstatus,
                        'status_trn' => $varstatustrn,
                        'tglperolehan' => $varaccdate,
                        'tglterimaasset' => $vardpjdate,
                        'masasusut' => $varsusut ,
                        'licence_qty' => $licence_qty
                        );

    $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', true);
    $query = $this->db1->insert('tblasset',$object);


    if($query)
    {

        $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        //sent email to accounting;
        $query=$this->assetmodel->dataemail('tambahassetproses');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $to = $row->to_name;
            $email = $row->email;
            $message = $row->message_template;
            $recipient_id = $row->recipient_id;
            $typework = 'Input Kode Asset';

            $send_email = $this->email_ctrl->send_email($to, $email, $message,$recipient_id,$typework, $userid );

            if ($send_mail == FALSE) {

                echo 'Could not Send Email';

            } else {
                echo 'Congrat!! Send Email Success';

            }


        }

        $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data['description'] = $this->session->userdata('userdescr');   
        $data['asset'] = $this->assetmodel->mstasset()->result_array();
        $data['pesan'] = "sukses isi data";
        $data['content'] = 'master/master_asset';
        $this->load->view('template', $data, FALSE);

    }
    else
    {
        $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data['description'] = $this->session->userdata('userdescr');           
        $data['pesan'] = "gagal isi data";
        $data[content] = 'master/master_asset';
        $this->load->view('template', $data, FALSE);

    }


}


public function send_email($fr_email, $to_email, $message, $recipient_id, $typework, $userid) { 

     $config = Array(
                      'protocol' => 'smtp',
                      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                      'smtp_port' => 465,
                      'smtp_user' => 'dianyulianti77@gmail.com', // change it to yours
                      'smtp_pass' => 'yul14nt1', // change it to yours
                      'mailtype' => 'html',
                      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                      'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                      'crlf' => "\r\n",
                      'newline' => "\r\n"
                    );

     $this->load->library('email', $config);
     $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
     $this->email->from($fr_email); // change it to yours
     $this->email->to($to_email);// change it to yours
     $this->email->subject('no.reply:need action on asset apps worklist');

      $message= /*-----------email body starts-----------*/
                'Hi ' . $to_email . ',' .

                'Ada Worklist yang harus kamu complete di Web Asset Applikasi, ' . $message .'!

                Silahkan Login ke :

                ' . base_url() . 'asset_apps/loguser' ;
              /*-----------email body ends-----------*/ 

     $this->email->message($message);

     if($this->email->send())
       {
           //Insert Into Worklist
            //get nextvalue
            $varcreation_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', true);
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT nextval('worklist_seq'::regclass) AS nextid");
            $row = $query->row();

            $worklist  =  array ( 
                                $id => $row->nextid;
                                $sender_id => $this->session->userdata('userid');
                                $recipient => $recipient_id;
                                $recipient_email => $to_email;
                                $typeworkdescr => $typework;
                                $status = 1;
                                $link = 'http://localhost/asset_apps/loguser';
                                $creation_date = $varcreation_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $user_id = $userid;
                                $update_date = $varcreation_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $update_user_id = $userid;
                                )

            $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', true);
            $query = $this->db1->insert('tblasset',$worklist);


        echo 'Email sent.';

        return TRUE

       }
      else
       {
         show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
         return FALSE; 
       }

  }
```

this is my Model :

```
public function dataemail($modul) {

    $this->db1=$this->load->database('default', true);
    return $this->db1->select('*')
                     ->from('tblemail')
                     ->get(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error. I move email_ctrl controller to Model.

Thanks,

Dian